Gitlab pipeline is not starting when create merge request
I need to trigger the gitlab pipeline automatically when creating a Merge Request. This pipeline should start automatically before clicking on merge. I have written this pipeline but not working as I expected. Now work this by clicking on the merge button. I need this to start with automatically creating a Merge Request.
default:
    tags:
        - $RUNNER_TAG

stages:
    - sonarqube
    - merge

# SonarQube scan on the source branch (relative branch)
sonarqube-check:
    stage: sonarqube
    image: node:slim
    cache:
        key: "${CI_JOB_NAME}"
        paths:
            - .sonar/cache
    script:
        - apt-get update -y
        - apt-get install -y git
        - git checkout $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME # Check out the branch related to the MR
        - git pull origin $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME # Pull latest changes
        - yarn install
        - yarn coverage:ci
        - npx sonarqube-scanner -Dproject.settings=./sonar-project-el.properties
        # Extract project key from sonar-project.properties
        - PROJECT_KEY=$(grep sonar.projectKey sonar-project-el.properties | cut -d '=' -f2)
        # Fetch the quality gate result from SonarQube API
        - |
          QUALITY_GATE=$(curl -s -u $SONAR_LOGIN: $SONAR_HOST_URL/api/qualitygates/project_status?projectKey=$PROJECT_KEY | jq -r .projectStatus.status)
          if [ "$QUALITY_GATE" != "OK" ]; then
            echo "SonarQube quality gate failed. MR cannot be merged."
            exit 1
          fi
    allow_failure: false
    rules:
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"'
      when: never
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH != $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH
      when: always

# Job for the automatic merge, triggered when the SonarQube check passes
merge-to-develop:
    stage: merge
    image: alpine/git
    script:
        - git fetch origin
        - git checkout develop
        - git pull origin develop
        - git merge --no-ff origin/$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME  # Merge dynamically determined MR branch into develop
        - git push origin develop  # Push the merged changes to develop
    rules:
        - if: '$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME == "develop"'  # Run only if MR targets develop
    when: on_success


How can I solve this issue?

In your sonarqube-check job, your rules are wrong:
rules:
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"'
      when: never
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH != $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH
      when: always

$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event" is the event that gets triggered when you create a new MR. Remove the when: never there.

I have tried this. But this is not working.

If you want this job to run on merge requests only, than remove the second rule (or append it to the first one if you must) and remove the when keyword.
If the rule is true (meaning this is a merge request) this job will run.
BTW this answer should be accepted.
